# AsyncPostback Trigger on gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, partial-postback

I was working on AsyncPostback trigger which is working fine when I type url

> localhost:49208/default.aspx

but when I remove default.aspx from url event handler not call.
here is my code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UPCompanyNews" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="ComUploaderImgDiv" class="cr-lodr" runat="server">
                    <asp:Image ID="ComUploaderImg" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/busy.gif" />
                </div>

                <div id="ComCarouselDiv" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;" runat="server">
                    <carousel:CompanyNews ID="CarouselCompanyNews" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" />

                </div>

            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="hiddenComNewsAsyTrigger" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:Button ID="hiddenComNewsAsyTrigger" runat="server" Text="AsyncUpdate" Style="display: none;" OnClick="LoadCompanyCarouselTrigger" />
```

event handler code

```
protected void LoadCompanyCarouselTrigger(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            CarouselCompanyNews.LoadCompanyNewsCarousel();
            ComUploaderImgDiv.Style["display"] = "none";
            ComCarouselDiv.Style["display"] = "block";
            LoadClientActivityTrigger();
            LoadMyStatTrigger(sender, e);
            LoadEventTrigger(sender, e);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by working fine?  From the code you posted you have a hidden button that will never be seen and so cannot be clicked.  Setting a hidden button as an `AsyncPostbackTrigger` does not mean it will automatically be clicked for you when the page is rendered.

Comment: Also:  if you mean that by placing this `http://localhost:49208/default.aspx` in a browser you see a rendered page with your carousel and that the address `http://localhost:49208` does nothing, then you simply need to make _**default.aspx**_ one of the default pages for your site in IIS or whatever webserver you're using.

Comment: I am really sorry not to mention jquery event. here is the code

`__doPostBack('<%= hiddenComNewsAsyTrigger.UniqueID %>', 'OnClick');`

Comment: that is not a jquery event. it is a call to the asp.net client webapi.  It will fire a postback that you can intercept, but it will not fire the `OnClick` event.  If you are trying to emulate a button click you can either intercept the postback in Page.Load event and call `LoadCompanyCarouselTrigger(...)` or you can replace the code above with `<%= ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(hiddenComNewsAsyTrigger, string.Empty) %>`